# Access to data that is shown by a list view in android

Tags: android

I have a `list view` in an android program. Each row of this `list view` has a `button`. When user clicks one of these `buttons`, an action must be performed on data that is shown by that row.

How can I *get access to that data and manipulate it*?

Answer (score 1):

Call `getItem()` on your `Adapter` to retrieve whatever the data is that is at that `position` within the `Adapter`. So, for example, if your `Adapter` is an `ArrayAdapter<Restaurant>`, `getItem()` will return the `Restaurant` for a given `position`.

Comment: In on click event of button,how can I get position of appropriate item in adapter?

Comment: @ebi: I would get rid of the `Button` and just have the user tap on the list row. That's how most Android apps are written. Otherwise, you are going to have to do work in `getView()` of your `Adapter` to teach each `Button` what position it is associated with (e.g., via `setTag()`), so it can use that information.

Comment: Indeed, I'm writing a TO DO application to learn android programming.
In my app all TO DO tasks are shown in a list view.For each item I provide a Checkbox view. So user can easily determine DONE or NOTDONE state for associated task. Each item in my adapter is an instance of a custom class called ToDoItem.This class has an instance variable named status that can be in DONE or NOTDONE state. To change the value of this variable I have to handle OnCheckedChanged event of CheckBox.How can I do this in my app?

Comment: @ebi: Either use a multiple-choice `ListView` (see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/Checklist), or use a multiple-selection contextual action bar (see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/ActionModeMC), or follow other patterns (see: Remember the Milk). Otherwise, you will need to do what I described in my preceding comment (see: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/RateList, which uses a `RatingBar` rather than a `CheckBox`).

Comment: Thank you very much CommonsWare.I use this https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/RateList and solved the problem.